# SAP Crystal Reports Gauge Chart - Format numbers without zeros

Tags: charts, formatting, crystal-reports

Is there a way to exclude the decimal values on a Crystal Reports gauge report.  In the example below, I would like to display "73,190" not "73,190.00".  Right clicking on the selected item and choosing Format Selected Item, does not provide an option to change the number format.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that your field is a number. In 'Field Explorer,' right click database fields and hit "Show Field Type..."

If your field is not a number, then it needs to be... Right click the number field in the report itself, and hit "Format Field..."

Go to the "Number" tab, and select a value without trailing decimals in the 'Style' box under "System Default Number Format."

[image: CR snapshot]